# Nested SQL queries in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, subquery

I have to run 1 query, then another with the results of the first.  I realize that I COULD just throw the first result set inside of an array then iterate through the array, but is there a way to just nest the queries so that I don't have to mess with the array?

Here is my current code:

```
    SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["wesdb1SQL"].ToString());
    SqlCommand strSQL2;
    SqlDataReader itemReader2;

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["wesdb1SQL"].ToString()))
    using (SqlCommand strSQL = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        strSQL.CommandText = "SELECT item_id,item_lot,item_title,item_est_lo,item_est_hi,item_timed_start,item_reserve FROM tblItem WHERE (item_sale_id=@item_sale_id) ORDER BY item_lot";

        strSQL.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@item_sale_id", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10, ParameterDirection.Input, true, 0, 0, "item_sale_id", DataRowVersion.Current, itemSaleId1_Var));

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader itemReader = strSQL.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (itemReader.Read())
                {
                    using (conn2)
                    using (strSQL2 = conn2.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        strSQL2.CommandText = "SELECT TOP (1) MAX(tblBidHistory.bid_price) AS bid_price, tblMailList.mail_Email1, tblBidHistory.bid_bidder_id, tblMailList.mail_FirstName, tblMailList.mail_LastName, tblBidHistory.bid_item_id FROM tblBidHistory INNER JOIN tblBidder ON tblBidHistory.bid_bidder_id = tblBidder.bidder_number AND (tblBidder.bidder_sale_id=@item_sale_id) INNER JOIN tblMailList ON tblBidder.bidder_mail_id = tblMailList.mail_ID GROUP BY tblMailList.mail_Email1, tblBidHistory.bid_bidder_id, tblMailList.mail_FirstName, tblMailList.mail_LastName, tblBidHistory.bid_item_id,tblBidHistory.bid_type,tblBidHistory.bid_date HAVING (tblBidHistory.bid_item_id=@item_id) AND (tblBidHistory.bid_type = '2') ORDER BY bid_price DESC,bid_date DESC";

                        strSQL2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@item_sale_id", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10, ParameterDirection.Input, true, 0, 0, "item_sale_id", DataRowVersion.Current, itemSaleId1_Var));
                        strSQL2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@item_id", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10, ParameterDirection.Input, true, 0, 0, "item_id", DataRowVersion.Current, itemReader["item_id"].ToString()));

                        try
                        {
                            conn2.Open();
                            using (itemReader2 = strSQL2.ExecuteReader())
                            {
                                if (itemReader2.Read())
                                {
                                    if (count % 2 == 0)
                                    {
                                        results_Var += "<tr><td colspan=\"2\"><font size=\"2\">" + itemReader["item_lot"].ToString() + " - <u>" + itemReader["item_title"].ToString() + "</u></font></td><td><font size=\"2\">$" + itemReader["item_est_lo"].ToString() + " - $" + itemReader["item_est_hi"].ToString() + "</font></td><td>" + itemReader2["bid_price"].ToString() + " - " + itemReader2["bid_bidder_id"].ToString() + " (" + itemReader2["mail_FirstName"].ToString() + " " + itemReader2["mail_LastName"].ToString() + ")</td><td><font size=\"2\">$" + itemReader2["bid_price"].ToString() + "</font></td></tr>";
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        results_Var += "<tr><td colspan=\"2\" bgcolor=\"#b0e0e6\"><font size=\"2\">" + itemReader["item_lot"].ToString() + " - <u>" + itemReader["item_title"].ToString() + "</u></font></td><td><font size=\"2\">$" + itemReader["item_est_lo"].ToString() + " - $" + itemReader["item_est_hi"].ToString() + "</font></td><td>" + itemReader2["bid_price"].ToString() + " - " + itemReader2["bid_bidder_id"].ToString() + " (" + itemReader2["mail_FirstName"].ToString() + " " + itemReader2["mail_LastName"].ToString() + ")</td><td><font size=\"2\">$" + itemReader2["bid_price"].ToString() + "</font></td></tr>";
                                    }
                                }
                                itemReader2.Close();
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception e1)
                        {
                            throw new Exception(e1.Message);
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            conn2.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
                itemReader.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e2)
        {
            throw new Exception(e2.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

The output of both queries is used to create a table of multiple rows of data.  Each row is one item in the database with the highest bidder's information including the bid itself, along with some category information.  The category information is the first query, and the unique item information is the second query (which is where you can see the table rows being built using both result sets).

**Edit**

I changed xQbert query a little and ended up with:

```
SELECT MAX(BH.bid_price) AS bid_price, ML.mail_Email1, BH.bid_bidder_id,  ML.mail_FirstName, ML.mail_LastName, BH.bid_item_id, I.item_lot, I.item_title,  I.item_est_lo, I.item_est_hi, I.item_timed_start, I.item_reserve  
FROM tblBidHistory BH 
INNER JOIN tblBidder B  ON BH.bid_bidder_id = B.bidder_number   AND (B.bidder_sale_id=@item_sale_id) 
INNER JOIN tblMailList ML   ON B.bidder_mail_id = ML.mail_ID 
INNER JOIN tblItem I   ON I.Item_ID = BH.Bid_item_id 
WHERE (I.item_sale_id=@item_sale_id) And (BH.bid_type = '2') 
GROUP BY ML.mail_Email1, BH.bid_bidder_id, ML.mail_FirstName, ML.mail_LastName, BH.bid_item_id, BH.bid_type, BH.bid_date, I.item_lot, I.item_title, I.item_est_lo, I.item_est_hi, I.item_timed_start, I.item_reserve
ORDER BY I.Item_Lot
```

This gives me data, but it gives me every bidder for each item instead of the top bidder for each item.  I'm not sure if I need to group differently, or maybe use a sub query.

Also, to do this, I'm just making 1 query.  However, I would still like to know how to make nested queries in SQL.

Comment: What database are you working with?

Comment: SQL.  If you are asking for something besides that, I have no clue. Sorry.  How would I find that out?

Comment: Would really be useful to see some sample expected output.  MS-SQL (2005/2008 etc), MySQL, Oracle, DB2, PostGres,

Comment: nikAdmin wants to know if you are using SQL Server, Oracle, mySQL, etc.   The connection string would tell you, but if you want to post that to show, be sure to remove the PASSWORD and USERID from it.

Comment: NiKAdmin, based on the use of TOP(1) in his query code, I am assuming it is Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: @James: Have you tried using `row_number()` (as demonstrated in my answer) to get one row per item_id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
select * from
(SELECT i.item_id,
       i.item_lot,
       i.item_title,
       i.item_est_lo,
       i.item_est_hi,
       i.item_timed_start,
       i.item_reserve,
       h.bid_price,
       l.mail_Email1,
       h.bid_bidder_id,
       l.mail_FirstName,
       l.mail_LastName,
       h.bid_item_id,
       row_number() over (partition by i.item_id 
                          order by h.bid_price DESC, h.bid_date DESC) rn
 FROM tblItem i 
 INNER JOIN tblBidHistory h
         on i.item_id = h.bid_item_id=i.item_id AND h.bid_type = '2' 
 INNER JOIN tblBidder b
         ON h.bid_bidder_id = b.bidder_number AND b.bidder_sale_id=i.item_sale_id
 INNER JOIN tblMailList l
         ON b.bidder_mail_id = l.mail_ID 
 WHERE i.item_sale_id=@item_sale_id) v
where rn=1
```

Comment: I tried adding the row_number() function (the entire line up to and including rn) to the end of my select statement, then wrapped all of it inside of another select statement where rn=1 and received the error > The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

I moved my order by clause outside to the first select statement and ordered by v.column and then started getting errors saying tblItem.item_id (and others) were not in a group by or aggregate function and couldn't be selected.

Comment: When I use the entire query, I get the error `Incorrect syntax near '('.`

Comment: @James: Sorry, I just noticed a missing `,` - try now.

Comment: No worries, I didn't notice it either.  Had to change one thing on here and add another.  On the first inner join on statement, I took out one of the i.item_id = because it was in there twice, and I added order by item_lot to the end of the entire statement.  This is really close.  I only get one row per item now, but it is not the highest bidding row, and there are some rows that are missing completely.  Of course, I see why...  There is no bidder data for those, and we are using inner joins instead of outer joins.  But still have an issue with it not pulling the highest bid/bidder.

Comment: This is really weird.  When I put this query directly in the SQL interface, it does pull the right data.  But when I use the query on my page, it does not.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and mark this as the right answer since the query is obviously correct.  But if you have any idea why it doesn't work in my page itself, please let me know.  Thanks~

Comment: I'm going to stop wracking my brain on this.  For whatever reason, the demo database and live database do not have the same data.  I thought a demo update had just been done last week, but I guess not.  This is indeed right.

Answer (score 1):

I highly doubt the below is correct: too many assumptions and lack of understanding of question: but this is one way to join them
Assuming item joins to BH via Bid_Item_ID
Added order by for I.Item_lot and added item data 
added item data to select and group by.

```
SELECT TOP (1) MAX(BH.bid_price) AS bid_price, ML.mail_Email1, BH.bid_bidder_id,
  ML.mail_FirstName, ML.mail_LastName, BH.bid_item_id, I.item_lot, I.item_title,
  I.item_est_lo, I.item_est_hi, I.item_timed_start, I.item_reserve  
FROM tblBidHistory BH
INNER JOIN tblBidder B
  ON BH.bid_bidder_id = B.bidder_number 
  AND (B.bidder_sale_id=@item_sale_id) 
INNER JOIN tblMailList ML 
  ON B.bidder_mail_id = ML.mail_ID
INNER JOIN tblItem I 
  ON I.Item_ID = BH.Bid_item_id
WHERE (I.item_sale_id=@item_sale_id)
GROUP BY ML.mail_Email1, BH.bid_bidder_id, 
  ML.mail_FirstName, ML.mail_LastName, BH.bid_item_id, BH.bid_type, BH.bid_date,
  I.item_lot, I.item_title, I.item_est_lo, I.item_est_hi, I.item_timed_start, 
  I.item_reserve  
HAVING (BH.bid_item_id=@item_id) AND (BH.bid_type = '2') 
ORDER BY I.Item_Lot, BH.bid_price DESC, BH.bid_date DESC
```

Comment: I think the OP wants the highest, latest bid for each item in a sale, rather than the highest, latest bid for any item in the sale.

Comment: @MarkBannister Yes, that's right.  I'm trying to get it for each individual item within the same sale.

Comment: And after minor tweeks, I get all the data, but I'm getting multiple rows of the same data in some cases.